# Converting csv file to dictionary

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I asked this question yesterday but am still stuck on it. I've written a function that currently reads a file correctly but there are a couple of problems.

The main problem I'm having is that I need to somehow skip the first line of the file and I'm not sure if I'm returning it as a dictionary. Here is an example of one of the files:

```
"Artist","Title","Year","Total  Height","Total  Width","Media","Country"
"Pablo Picasso","Guernica","1937","349.0","776.0","oil  paint","Spain"
"Vincent van Gogh","Cafe Terrace at Night","1888","81.0","65.5","oil paint","Netherlands"
"Leonardo da Vinci","Mona Lisa","1503","76.8","53.0","oil paint","France"
"Vincent van Gogh","Self-Portrait with Bandaged Ear","1889","51.0","45.0","oil paint","USA"
"Leonardo da Vinci","Portrait of Isabella d'Este","1499","63.0","46.0","chalk","France"
"Leonardo da Vinci","The Last Supper","1495","460.0","880.0","tempera","Italy"
```

I need to read a file like the one above and convert it into a dictionary that looks like this:

```
sample_dict = {
        "Pablo Picasso":    [("Guernica", 1937, 349.0,  776.0, "oil paint", "Spain")],
        "Leonardo da Vinci": [("Mona Lisa", 1503, 76.8, 53.0, "oil paint", "France"),
                             ("Portrait of Isabella d'Este", 1499, 63.0, 46.0, "chalk", "France"),
                             ("The Last Supper", 1495, 460.0, 880.0, "tempera", "Italy")],
        "Vincent van Gogh": [("Cafe Terrace at Night", 1888, 81.0, 65.5, "oil paint", "Netherlands"),
                             ("Self-Portrait with Bandaged Ear",1889, 51.0, 45.0, "oil paint", "USA")]
      }
```

Here's what I have so far. My current code works but does not convert the file into a dictionary like the example above. Thanks for any help

```
def convertLines(lines):
    head = lines[0]
    del lines[0]
    infoDict = {}
    for line in lines:
        infoDict[line.split(",")[0]] = [tuple(line.split(",")[1:])]
    return infoDict

def read_file(filename):
    thefile = open(filename, "r")
    lines = []
    for i in thefile:
        lines.append(i)
    thefile.close()
    mydict = convertLines(read_file(filename))
    return lines
```

Would just a couple small changes to my code return the correct result or would I need to approach this differently? It does appear that my current code reads the full file. Thanks for any help

Edit: @Julien It was working (but not correctly) until I made some revisions this morning it is now giving a recursion error.

Comment: What result do you get that you are unhappy with? This is the kind of info that is relevant so share it please!

Comment: I bet you are just overwriting each the result for each artist instead of appending to the list...

Comment: My current code is actually giving a recursion error but basically I haven't been able to create a dictionary where the keys are the artist names and the values are their paintings so for the above example there should be 3 keys even though the names can repeat in the file and the values are their paintings (1 for Picasso, 3 for da Vinci, and 2 for van Gogh)

Comment: That sounds like it could be the issue

Comment: Why do you say your code works then if it gives an error? And if it gives an error then share the error...

Comment: Is this related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566245/function-read-a-file-then-add-multiple-items-to-dictionary) question? Did you change your name? This seems familiar ;-)

Comment: @Maurice I saw that yesterday and am actually having trouble with that function as well but that is someone else working on similar functions and not me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want this:

```
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as thefile:
        mydict = convertLines(thefile.readlines()))
        return mydict
```

your current function is infinitely calling itself... Then fix your `convertLines` function if it needs to.

Comment: Thank you I think this is on the right track do you know whats wrong with the convertLines function as now it is saying "maximum recursion depth exceeded"

Comment: Thanks its saying "Diff is x characters long" and the x in all cases is an outrageous number like 2000 when it should be smaller. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: How could I? Your code doesn't have any 'Diff'. You should read [ask].

Comment: I think diff is referring to the dictionary and every time I run the code the value seems to change for each case. This is definitely the toughest function I've had to program its been over a full day since i started

Answer (score 0):

This should simplify your code a bit, however I have left dealing with the header row up to you.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

artists = defaultdict(list)

with open('artists.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        artists[row[0]].append(row[1:-1])
```